# Get UITableView headers/footers

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

Ok, so I have this issue where I need to get access to the headers/footers displayed in a UITableView.  Moreover, I need to do this from a subclass of UITableView (so I can't simply assign tags to the view from the UITableView Delegate).  UITableView does keep an array of visible headers and footers but it provides no access to those arrays even to the subclass, which I personally think is asinine.

I need this so that I can provide a custom drag-n'-drop insertion/move user interface.  I'm trying to get it to work almost exactly like Apple's own rearranging interface, but of course, with my own custom implementation (like the ability to drag from another table). Everything works perfectly except for the headers/footers.

At the moment I'm trying to hack it by iterating through all the subviews of UITableView.  I'm pretty sure that the only subviews of UITableView is: backgroundView, UITableViewCells, and Headers/Footers. So I just need to determine which are UITableViewCells (very easy), which is the background view (also easy) and which are headers/footers (not so easy).  I'm pretty sure I can do it this way but it's definitely a hack and I'd rather find a better way if possible.

***UPDATE***

I'm overriding the `- (void) setDelegate:(id<UITableViewDelegate>)delegate` method and checking to see if the delegate responds to the appropriate selectors to generate headers/footers (and set BOOL's appropriately).  This is making it a lot easier to determine what a particular subview is since the progression of header -> cells -> footer is predictable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say you can't use UITableView delegate methods, but did you consider letting the UITableView subclass object be its own delegate? Create a separate property on the subclass called realDelegate and pass any other delegate calls through to that.

Comment: That's an interesting idea.  The only problem I see with it is I'm not sure whether UITableView alters it's behavior based on what its delegate responds to.  It I implement the subclass as it's own delegate then I have to respond to everything, even though it's delegate may not.  There probably are ways to make that work, so if my current approach doesn't work yours is next in line. :)

Comment: Ok, your solution worked.  Didn't have too much trouble with the delegate and I definitely needed definitive access to all the headers/footers to make it work properly.  Thanks!

Comment: Don't forget about if ([self.delegate respondstoSelector:])for deciding whether to pass on to the "real delegate"

Comment: Oh yeah, definitely.  I use the delegate pattern in several places in my app so I'm quite familiar with that method.  So far the code has been a lot more complicated than I anticipated, especially when I move across section boundaries. Guessing which views were headers/footers would have made this all impossible.  So thanks again!